How to inherit application.yml from parent repo in Spring?
I have a parent repository called ParentA and a child repository called ChildA. ParentA has a few projects with one being ProjectA and in ProjectA/pom.xml there is a dependency for 'spring-boot-starter-web'.
Structure:
ParentA
├── ProjectA
│   └── pom.xml
│   └── src/main/resources/application.yml
ChildA : ParentA
│   └── src/main/resources/application.xml
I now want my ChildA to use both the settings from the parent application.yml as well as its own application.yml in order to set the following properties from LogBack.
logging:
  logback:
    rollingpolicy:
      total-size-cap: 100KB
      max-history: 1
      max-file-size: 1KB

These settings should be inherited from the parent project. But for some reason they are not. It does not matter if I have application.yml in the src/main/resources/ or ProjectA/src/main/resources/. Nothing seems to work.
Now I am experimenting with just creating a logback.xml file in ProjectA instead. However, the default settings that Spring claim to have is that it only produces logs to the console and does NOT append to files. I am seeing very different behavior though, even when I don't configure or change the defaults at all.
So my two issues are:

Why does having application.yml in a parent repo not seem to be applied in my child repository?
and how come the default behavior of Spring logging not match the documentation?

I am using Spring Boot v3.3.4 and I am referring to these two links:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/logging.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/how-to/logging.html

my solution to this is to have a configuration class loading the parent's "custom" properties in addition to the standard application.properties. This class is also part of the parent code. The @Configuration annotation ensures that it is loaded also in the child project.
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:parent.properties")
public class ParentPropertiesLoader {
}

As you might guess the property class is called parent.properties placed in parent projects resource.
I assume yaml would also work the same.

Thanks for the reply!
Yml files are not supported by @PropertySource but using .properties format does indeed work like you suggested. However.. The configurations that I set on the parent level can not be changed at the child level. If I have a property myProperty.myValue=1 and then I do:
myProperty:
myValue: 0
inside my application.yml on the child it does not change the value as the parent has control over it.

I also tried spring.config.import in my child application.yml and while it does load the configurations from the parent I am not able to override any of it inside my application.yml in the child.

Another note. If I create application.yaml in my parent repository the configurations are loaded from it in the child repository. I am also able to override them in application.yml. I just wished I could somehow give my application.yaml a custom name so it doesn't grab the .yaml extension that I might wish to use later for my child project. It is just very important that Im able to override what ever the parent provides.
